# How can I figure out my SQL Server address without having the Management Studio installed?

Tags: sql-server, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2010

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed. It appears in the add/remove programs window.

How can I create/delete/alter tables and find the address of my server if I don't have Management Studio installed?

I'd like to create the tables and such directly in Visual Studio 2010 premium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click View, Server Explorer to show the Server Explorer pane.
Then click Add Connection (on top of the pane) and add a connection to your SQL Server instance.

You can then see the server under Data Connections, and run queries or modify structure by interacting with the tree.

Comment: I only see Connect to Database/Connect to Server. Neither show me the name of the Server. They expect me to type in the name manually. :(

Comment: Try the down arrow.  Alternatively, type `localhost` (or, for Express, `.\SQLExpress`)

Comment: It appears I only have SQL Express (judging from services.msc window) - what can I do?